# asp.net calendar control previous date selection problem?

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

friends,

i am using asp.net calendar control on page.

dynamically i am assigning it previous month date value.
it selects that date which is fine but not month

so the calendar shows current month when i use previous button then that date is selected.
any one guide me what is the solution?

my code

```
calstarting.SelectedDate = item.StartDate; // previous month date
            calending.SelectedDate = item.EndDate; // previous month date
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
Calendar1.TodaysDate= item.StartDate;
Calendar1.SelectedDate = item.StartDate;
```

Instead of `SelectedDate` use `TodaysDate` and then use `SelectedDate` to show that date selected.

Comment: yes you are right.. thanks i got it too and posted both solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution.

in order to show previous date with that month and date selected on the screen there are two ways...

both working for me.

calControl1.SelectedDate = item.StartDate; 
calControl1.TodaysDate = item.StartDate;

OR

calControl2.SelectedDate =  item.EndDate;   // to select that date
calControl2.VisibleDate = item.EndDate; // to select that perticular month on calender quite hidden attribute